# DataBinding & LiveData : two implementations (Kotlin & Java) and can't make the Java impl working

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I'm facing issues while using DataBinding and LiveData in a Java projet. I followed a previous course in Kotlin and when I try to implement the same behaviors I just can't make it work. I'm clearly missing something in terms of understanding so I'd like to have you thoughts.

I'll paste the code from the Kotlin (working) example and then the Java (not working) one.

### KOTLIN

**score_fragment.xml**

```
...
<data>

    <variable
        name="scoreViewModel"
        type="com.example.android.guesstheword.screens.score.ScoreViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/score_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.score.ScoreFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score_text"
        ...
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(scoreViewModel.score)}"
        .../>
...
```

**ScoreFragment.kt**

```
class ScoreFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var viewModelFactory: ScoreViewModelFactory
private lateinit var viewModel: ScoreViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

        // Inflate view and obtain an instance of the binding class.
        val binding: ScoreFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater,
                R.layout.score_fragment,
                container,
                false
        )

        // Get args using by navArgs property delegate
        val scoreFragmentArgs by navArgs<ScoreFragmentArgs>()

        viewModelFactory = ScoreViewModelFactory(scoreFragmentArgs.score)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
                .get(ScoreViewModel::class.java)

        binding.scoreViewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

**ScoreViewModel.kt**

```
class ScoreViewModel(finalScore: Int) : ViewModel() {

    private val _score = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val score: LiveData<Int>
        get() = _score

    private val _eventPlayAgain = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val eventPlayAgain: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _eventPlayAgain

    init {
        Timber.i("ScoreViewModel created")
        _score.value = finalScore
    }

    fun onPlayAgain() {
        _eventPlayAgain.value = true
    }

    fun onPlayAgainComplete() {
        _eventPlayAgain.value = false
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        Timber.i("ScoreViewModel cleared")
    }
}
```

**Explanations** : let's focus only on the score value. In ScoreViewModel the value is of type LiveData. When the fragment's launched, the value is correctly displayed on the screen through "@{String.valueOf(scoreViewModel.score)}". This works correctly.

### JAVA

**activity_main.xml**

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="noteViewModel"
        type="com.example.architectureapp.viewModel.NoteViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:text="@{noteViewModel.test}" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private NoteViewModel mNoteViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        mNoteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
        binding.setNoteViewModel(mNoteViewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    }
}
```

**NoteViewModel**

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    public MutableLiveData<String> test = new MutableLiveData<>("TesT");

    public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }
}
```

**Explanations** : here I'm setting a MutableLiveData test whith a value of "TesT" and then I intent to display it using android:text="@{noteViewModel.test}". But the text is never displayed and remains blank.

Obviously there is something wrong but despite the syntaxic differences between the two implementations I just can't figure out why the Java version is not displaying the value in the Textview.

### EDIT

Thanks to Rajnish suryavanshi I was not getting my binding the right way, I had to only use :

**binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);**

This one set the content view with the layout provided AND return the binding. 
Alternatively you can do :

**binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());** (returns the binding but does not set the content view)

**setContentView(binding.getRoot());** (set the content view with the binding root view)

I found this misleading -> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions

It states that we can replace

**ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);**

by

**ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());**

which is not the same !

Happy to get the subtility now !

Comment: add the getter method for test mutable live data.

Comment: use android:text="@{safeUnbox(viewModel. test)}"

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi, I tried but no luck. By the way and for the purpose of the example test is declared public so no need for a getter.

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu, I get a "cannot find method safeUnbox(java.lang.String) in class androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding". I have read somewhere that this can happen when using two way binding, but it's not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on this two lines.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
```

You are not creating your binding while inflating the layout. Instead of `setContentView` use `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);`

And now you can get the view using layout inflater

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
```

Comment: Hum actually this does not work but you've put me on the right path. I'm confused about what inflating actually does. Doing :
**DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());**
does not work, but this :
**binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());**
and this :
**binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);**
work. This was misleading -> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions